# maven jqgrid tag not found

Tags: maven, jsp

I wrote jqgrid in pom.xml

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/jqgrid  -->

    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>

        <artifactId>jqgrid</artifactId>

        <version>4.7.0</version>

    </dependency>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGBQl.png)

And then JSP

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/jqgrid/4.7.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
```

I wrote this this way, but console can not find it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: consol error then

Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8090/jqgrid/4.7.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: Solved : <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="webjars/jqgrid/4.7.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />